# How to filter with taxonomy term (with depth) for a user based view

Tags: 7, views

There is no filter by taxonomy term with depth option when I filter my view of users. I can only filter by a single exact term, so filtering by "Europe" doesn't find users with "France". All the content views allow this filter, so how do i get it for users?

All my content an users are associated with a taxonomy term for their Location:

Europe

- France
- Germany

North America

- USA
- Canada

etc etc